# Exclude Gradle dependency at debug

Tags: grails, gradle, dependency-management

I'm using Grails plugin to execute (war and debug) Grails 2.5.0 project.
It seems one of dependencies contain older dependency than I would like to you. When I war a project correct version is used, but at debug it uses older dependenvy version:

```
dependencies {
    bootstrap "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.50" // No container is deployed by default, so add this
    // plugins for the compile step
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.3"
    compile("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:1.5.2") {
        exclude module: 'xml-apis'
        exclude module: 'joda-time'
    }
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.8'

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ("org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.8.1") { exclude module: 'xml-apis' } // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0"
}
```

So at debug I have joda-time 1.6 which is shipped with spring-security-rest:1.5.2. But when war-ed joda-time version is 2.3